# splitting a number into the integer and decimal parts GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to split a number into its integer and decimal parts?

I've tried the int() "function":

int(5.5) = 5.

But I've got no idea how do I get the decimal?

**Example:**

(I have)

a = 12.34

(I want)

b = 12
c = 34

> a = 12.34
>
> b = int(a)
>
> c = ????

Thanks!!!!

(Update)

My specific problem, here we have (thanks again for the support)

I have a set of data, with different blocks. For each block, I want to make the same plot.
The title of the plot and the name of the output png depends on the block.

With this goal in mind I've created a  loop

```
do for [j=0:int(A_blocks-2)]{

i=0 + 0.4*j

set output 'Mz_NMcs5000_Hext'.i.'_JC1_JSn05_JIntn05_R11_tSh2.png'

set title "H = '.i.'  J_C = 1  J_S = J_{Int} = - 0.5"

plot filename index j using 1:5 w lp pt 5 lt rgb "black" title "Mag_T", "" index j u 1:20  w lp pt 9 lt rgb "red" title "Mag_{Int-S}"
}
```

The problem I have is that I only can concatenate using the dot if the value is an integer. I get this error:

> internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Well, adding unrelated code doesn't help not getting rejected. If the question is clear and neither a duplicate nor obvious to answer by a simple web search you will get an answer. Should `1.23` return `23`, and `1.230` return `230`? What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new with this and still trying to guess how it works

Comment: that's fine. So, do you want `23` or `230` in case of `1.230`? What do you want to get for example for `5.001`... `1`? and what do you want to get for `5.01` and `5.1`? `1` as well? I doubt. Please clarify.

Comment: ok. this looks like a xy-problem, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What do you actually want to achieve? Including a float number into a filename and a title?

Comment: Yes, I want to include a float number into a filename and title. Exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include a float number into a title or a file name use the string formatting via `sprintf()`, check `help sprintf` and `help format specifiers`.

```
a = 1.234
myFile = sprintf("MyFileName_%g_MoreParameters.png",a)
print myFile
```

Result:

```
MyFileName_1.234_MoreParameters.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have shifted, but the answer to the original question as asked is

```
gnuplot> a = 5.5555555555555
gnuplot> b = a - floor(a)
gnuplot> print b
0.5555555555555
```

Comment: Thanks!!! And is there a way to convert 0.555555555 into an integer 555555555 ?

Comment: That is not a uniquely-defined operation.  How many decimal places of precision to keep? Round up or round down?

Comment: Well, I guess that for 0.123 ---> 123 and for 1.203500 ---> 2035. Now, it isn't a big deal, cause I need it for the title and output file name. Thanks again.